# Largest number of job position of employees at a multiple Companies using SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to find out the most popular job position employees are working at a combination of companies. If there is a tie, however, then both are added to the table.

I have a file called employees_data.txt.
I have their name, company, job position, and age in that order.

```
Natali, Google, IT, 45
Nadia, Facebook, Sales, 25
Jacob, Google, IT, 32
Leonard, Bing, Custodian, 65
Kami, Amazon, Driver, 43
Paul, Facebook, Engineer, 31
Ashley, Walmart, IT, 34
Robert, Fedex, IT, 27
Rebecca, Ups, Driver, 29
Mal, Apple, Custodian, 73
Erin, Bing, Sales, 38
```

I know the expected outcome should be the IT position, I'm just unsure the sql command to read through and keep track of the positions.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feels like homework :laugh:

You need an aggregate (count, sum, min,max, etc,.) and a group by

```
select count(*), position
from t
group by position
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dUqdZaUGpHTAYv8vH1YhU1/0

to only return the 'top record' we can use a self join with row_number calculation like this... probably an easier and cleaner way to do it, but you get the idea.

```
SELECT count(*) as recordcount, t.position
FROM t
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT *
        ,row_number() OVER (
            ORDER BY recordCount DESC
            ) AS rn
        
    FROM (
        SELECT count(*) AS recordCount
            ,position
        FROM t
        GROUP BY position
        ) as a
    ) d ON t.position = d.position
    AND d.rn = 1

group by t.position
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dUqdZaUGpHTAYv8vH1YhU1/1

Comment: This isn't a homework question, I tried coming up with different problems so I can learn more SQL for different instances because my professor doesn't teach us anything.

Comment: Ah, nice. sorry if i was being rude! I am trying to be more active on stack overflow to learn more sql techniques too.

Answer (score 1):

You want aggregation with a window function.  That is:

```
select p.*
from (select position, count(*) as cnt,
             rank() over (order by count(*) desc) as seqnum
      from t
      group by position
     ) p
where seqnum = 1;
```

In the most recent version of Postgres, you don't even need a subquery because it now supports `with ties`:

```
select position, count(*) as cnt
from t
group by position
order by count(*) desc
fetch first 1 row with ties;
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your assignment calls for a query something along these lines:

```
select job_position
from employees_data
group by job_position
order by count(*) desc
fetch first 1 row with ties
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the table is call jobpositions, and the columns are as follows:
name, company, position,age

I would use:

select * from (
select position, COUNT(position) as countpos, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY count(position) DESC)  as numpos
from jobpositions group by position order by count(position) desc
) tb1 where tb1.numpos=1

This seems to work in postgres, and i like it because it is simple.